# Hangman - Find 2 characters python

Tags: python, indexing

I've this assignment to make a Hangman program in Python. He is what I've done so far:

```
newList = []
f = open('words.txt','r')
for i in range(120):
    wlist=f.readline()
    newList.append(wlist)
print newList
print len(newList)

import random
a=(random.choice(newList))
c=len(a)-1
print a
e='_ ' * c
print "I'm thinking of the", c, "- letter word:", e
b=raw_input("Make a choice: ")

s=list(e)
if b in a:
    p=a.index(b)
    s[p*2]=b
    print p
    print ''.join(s)
```

The thing is that if the word has two or more same letters (for example: position) and the user guesses the letter o the it will appear _ o _ _ _ _ _ _ and not _ o _ _ _ _ o _! 
How can I fix that? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

```
def findIndexes(s, ch):
    return [i for i, letter in enumerate(s) if letter == ch]

a="position"
print (a)
c=len(a)

e = '_ ' * c
print ("I'm thinking of the", c, "- letter word:", e)
b = raw_input("Make a choice: ")

s=list(e)
if b in a:
    indx = findIndexes(a,b)
    for i in indx:
        s[i*2]=b
        print (i)
    print (''.join(s))
```

Output for input `o`:

```
position
I'm thinking of the 8 - letter word: _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 
Make a choice: o
1
6
_ o _ _ _ _ o _
```

Output for input `n`:

```
position
I'm thinking of the 8 - letter word: _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 
Make a choice: n
7
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ n
```

Since I don't have your txt, I assigned `a` myself.

About code, I defined a function which finds all occurences of a letter in a string using [enumerate](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#enumerate) and put them in a list. Then I used that list to switch underscores at those indexes to input letter.